# Plug-in Installation Problem

Tags: apt, updates, permissions, software-center

when i am trying to install required plug-ins to play music,the following notice is coming:

```
Failed to fetch http:/bd.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/libd/libdvdread/libdvdread4_4.2.0+20121016-1ubuntu1.1_i386.deb 403  Forbidden
Failed to fetch http:/bd.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/libd/libdvdnav/libdvdnav4_4.2.0+20130225-1ubuntu0.1_i386.deb 403  Forbidden
Failed to fetch http:/bd.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/libm/libmad/libmad0_0.15.1b-7ubuntu2_i386.deb 403  Forbidden
Failed to fetch http:/bd.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/l/lame/libmp3lame0_3.99.5+repack1-3_i386.deb 403  Forbidden
Failed to fetch http:/bd.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/m/mpeg2dec/libmpeg2-4_0.5.1-5_i386.deb 403  Forbidden
Failed to fetch http:/bd.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/o/opencore-amr/libopencore-amrnb0_0.1.3-2_i386.deb 403  Forbidden
Failed to fetch http:/bd.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/o/opencore-amr/libopencore-amrwb0_0.1.3-2_i386.deb 403  Forbidden
Failed to fetch http:/bd.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/x/x264/libx264-123_0.123.2189+git35cf912-1_i386.deb 403  Forbidden
Failed to fetch http:/bd.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/a/a52dec/liba52-0.7.4_0.7.4-16build1_i386.deb 403  Forbidden
Failed to fetch http:/bd.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/libs/libsidplay/libsidplay1_1.36.59-5_i386.deb 403  Forbidden
Failed to fetch http:/bd.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/t/twolame/libtwolame0_0.3.13-1build1_i386.deb 403  Forbidden
Failed to fetch http:/bd.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/g/gst-plugins-ugly1.0/gstreamer1.0-plugins-ugly_1.0.6-1_i386.deb 403  Forbidden
```

what should I do now?....and is there any better Music Player than Rhythmbox?
(i had to cut off one '/' after every http,cause i am not allowed to post more than 2 links.

Comment: Have you connected to internet properly?

Comment: Yes!The same notice is being showed there too, but i have connected to internet properly.

Comment: I think the bd.archive.ubuntu.com is not working properly and there is some server trouble you should try installing form other country server and the most trusted and nearest is in.archive.ubuntu.com

Comment: Try to change download server from Software & Updates. (use main server or choose best download server)

Answer (score 0):

Try to update the repositories

```
sudo apt-get update
```

this will downloads the package lists from the repositories and "updates" them to get information on the newest versions of packages and their dependencies.

If that fails try change to a different software server.

> (Software & Updates > Ubuntu Software > Downlaod from: Main Server)

For an alternative to Rythmbox try;

**Banshee Media Player**